# Laravel and Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, laravel

Wordpress is greate, and I've done some project with Laravel. It's great also ! I am thinking how can I intergate between 2 platform. F

or specific. How could I use Laravel to build plugin for wordpresss ?

Comment: Wordpress isn't great :) http://lostechies.com/bradcarleton/2014/01/22/why-wordpress-sucks-and-what-you-can-do-about-it/

Comment: Laravel shoulnd't be used to build plugins for WordPress.

Comment: Laravel is a framework. WordPress is a CMS. These are important differences!!! Please keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Would be a pretty bad idea

Why not use the Laravel CMS package, or maybe something like October CMS.

Answer (score 0):

After all these years. Now I find out a solution for this. This is exactly whats I mean. Some Developers need to develop in Wordpress the way they develop Laravel.

https://typerocket.com/